# Is an electron's charge arbitrarily called negative?

Tags: electrons

In *Cosmos* Carl Sagan writes

> Electrons are electrically charged, as their name suggests. The charge is arbitrarily called negative.

Is this true (I know the book is out of date, like how Titan is called the largest moon in the solar system)? If so, why is it negatively charged? Was the proton discovered first and then they just made an opposite, because now that I think about it, a negative charge doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to put something positive in the center of the atom, and something negative around this center.

Comment: Formal polarity and potential scale orientation in macroscale electrotechnics has been established before electron was discovered as the first known elementary particle  and before foundations of quantum physics has been laid.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/567/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked and answered several times on Physics.SE (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142150; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176589; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377036; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/475823). Including @Loong's [XKCD 567 reference, too](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17109).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is arbitrary in the sense that you could redefine everything that relates to the charge of electrons and protons. Once you call one charge negative or positive (like that of the electron), all other charges (proton, positron, cation, anion, cathode, anode, muon, up quark, down quark, glass/fur, glass/silk) follow.

However, the electron is named after amber ([from Greek ēlektron "amber"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/electron)):

> Thus, when amber is rubbed with fur, electrons are transferred from the fur to the amber, giving the amber an excess of electrons, and, hence, a negative charge, and the fur a deficit of electrons, and, hence, a positive charge.

Source: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/316/lectures/node12.html

So it makes sense to use the name electron for the particle that has the same charge as amber rubbed with fur. Whether you call it negative or positive is arbitrary, but it makes sense to stick with negative with all the publications that came out in more than a century since it was discovered.